# Best practise for populating access token with external claims

Tags: identityserver4

We have implemented IdSrv4 on top of AspNetCore Identity and we use ADFS as external IdP. From ADFS we wan´t to get the users AD-groups, upn and som other claims. The claims will be used both inside our IdSrv4 implementation, but will also be sent to our API-resources as part of the access token.

The current situation in our IdSrv4 implementation:

- ADFS has been configured so that it emits the claims that we want and in our IdSrv4 implementation those claims are received as expected in the "ExternalLoginCallback" method of the AccountController.
- IProfileService has been implemented in order to fill the "IssuedClaims" list with claims.

BUT, I haven't managed to build the connection between those to steps. What is the preferred way to preserve the claims received in "ExternalLoginCallback" and put them into the generated access_token in the IProfileService class?

Right now I have managed to get it *working* by saving the token using the method "UpdateExternalAuthenticationTokensAsync", which will save the token in the database. Then in the profile service I fetch the token and read the claims into the emitted token.

But this doesn't feel right and while searching for the proper way I´ve seen examples use the class IdentityServerUser that has "AdditionalClaims" property, but I can't find a way to plug that type into the event flow. 
Also, when configuring the external IdP you have these "ClaimActions" that can be mapped, but I don't understand what they are.
Finally, I assume that the database tables "IdentityClaims" and "ClientClaims" with corresponding entities *should* be used for this purpose but I can´t figure out how. Or should they be saved in the "AspNetUserClaims" table to save the actual claim type/values and not only claim mappings?

So basically, there must be a best practice for this scenario that seem to avoid me and I would be greatful if someone could share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue in my problem was that the problems I first encountered with persisting the Claims in the AspNetIdentity-Db led me to a wild goose chase.

Returning to this after a week or so made me give this another shot. Turns out that the DI injected "_userManager" wasn't "connected" to the current DI injected "_signInManager". If someone has an explanation for this, please share!

What did work was to use the "_signInManager.UserManager" to update Claims on the user. This properly stores the Claims in the "AspNetUserClaims" table, and can then be retrieved in the profile service.

UPDATE 1:
Of course there was a logical answer to that as well. A user manager is created by default even if you don't call "AddUserManager" on your identity setup during startup. BUT, in my case I have extended the IdentityUser class and now by doing it like this it all works as excpected (where "UserIdentity" is my derived class):

```
.AddIdentity<TUserIdentity, TUserIdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TIdentityDbContext>()
            .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<UserIdentity>>()
            .AddUserManager<UserManager<UserIdentity>>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```